# ReactJS - componentWillUpdate on parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In `React` if a child component updates, whether props or states, will parent's `componentWillUpdate` be called?

Comment: Data flows one way ... so I'm not sure what you mean (and the parent was the component that would have changed a child's properties)? How would the parent's `componentWillUpdate` be triggered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a component gets its props from its parent, if its props change, then it means by definition that the parent must have rerendered. However, a component that updates its own state does not cause its parent to change in any way, and so does not trigger `componentWillUpdate` on its parent.